# ResourceIdentityRequired Error - Azure Policy assignments must include a 'managed identity'

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-policy

I am trying to assign [this policy](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/building-a-policy-to-deploy-the-new-azure-monitor-agent/ba-p/2234423) But I am receiving  error below:

```
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name  $policyNameToAssign -DisplayName $PolicyDisplayName -Scope $Subscription -PolicyDefinition $definition
# Enter: DCRResourceID string
New-AzPolicyAssignment: ResourceIdentityRequired : The policy assignment 'PolicyName' request is invalid. Policy assignments must include a 'managed identity' when assigning 'DeployIfNotExists' policy definitions. Please see https://aka.ms/azurepolicyremediation for usage information.
```

What is missing in the policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, policies with the `deployIfNotExists` and `modify` effect
> types must specify **identity** while doing policy assignments from CLI/PowerShell.

When I ran below PowerShell script to assign policy without including any identity, I too got **same error** as below:

```
$assignmentName = "Devipolicy"
$subscriptionId = "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-xxxxxxxx"
$policyDefName = "sripolicy"

# Get the policy definition
$policyDefinition = Get-AzPolicyDefinition | Where-Object { $_.Properties.DisplayName -eq $policyDefName }

New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name $assignmentName -Scope $subscriptionId -PolicyDefinition $policyDefinition
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to add either *system-assigned* or
> *user-assigned* managed identity by including **identity** related parameters in command, that are required to deploy resources and edit
> tags on existing resources respectively.

In my case, I modified the script by including **`-IdentityType`** parameter with 'SystemAssigned' value and got the **response** successfully like below:

```
$assignmentName = "Devipolicy"
$subscriptionId = "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-xxxxxxxx"
$policyDefName = "sripolicy"

# Get the policy definition
$policyDefinition = Get-AzPolicyDefinition | Where-Object { $_.Properties.DisplayName -eq $policyDefName }

New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name $assignmentName -Scope $subscriptionId -PolicyDefinition $policyDefinition -Location 'eastus' -IdentityType 'SystemAssigned'
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, policy assignment created with ***system-assigned*** managed identity like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[New-AzPolicyAssignment: ResourceIdentityRequired - GitHub by **ishepherd**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/11996)

Comment: Can we specify pre-existing User Assigned managed id **GUID** to the command line flag `IdentityType` in case if its UAMI?

Comment: Yes, you can specify pre-existing User Assigned managed id GUID. Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-10.2.0#example-6-policy-assignment-with-a-user-assigned-managed-identity)